# Как читаются эти строки (расшифровываются)?

Tags: reactjs

Весь код реализует добавление или удаление классов (переключение). 
Я прокомментировал строки.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isActive: false,
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ isActive: !state.isActive }));   // stirng №1
  };  

  render() {
    const { isActive } = this.state;    // stirng №2

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Try it</button>   //stirng №3
        <div className={isActive ? 'mystyle' : ''}>   //stirng №4
          This is a DIV element.
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Как читаются эти строки (расшифровываются)? Не только то что они делают, но и как они читаются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. функция handleClick инвертирует внутренние состояние компонента state.isActive = true | false
2. создает константу внутри функции render isActive, значение берется из this.state (состояния компонента)
3. при клике запускается функция handleClick
4. присваивает стиль если isActive = true или стирает его для элемента div